# How to disable or reduce SSL logging in Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere-6.1

The logs in Websphere Appplication Server are thrashing a lot with redundnant details on SSL certificates used for each message sent over https.

Does anyone know how to disable this in WAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you dont have SSL debug turned on, javax.net.debug?
This can be set as a SystemProperty or though the admin console:

This link has details
http://java-utilities.blogspot.com/2009/02/enable-ssl-debugging-in-ibm-websphere.html

Hope this helps.